# Can you get a simultaneous animation and transition in PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation, slideshow

I have a presentation with a slide that, while it is in the process of crossfading to the next slide, I want to perform an animation. The animation and transition are of the same duration, so they should complete at the same time.

I attempted to accomplish this effect by inserting a duplicate of the slide with an auto-advance timer of 0 and an animation that auto-triggers on slide load, but PowerPoint blocks the transition until the animation is complete.

Is it possible to get an animation to occur during a slide transition?

Comment: For the animation have you tried putting it ontop and choosing 'with previous'? Also what version of PowerPoint are you using?

Comment: @RACING121 2016. That was my thought for how to accomplish this task, but Powerpoint blocked the transition until the animation was complete.

Comment: Can you cheat?  Instead of using a slide transition, fade the first slide to an image of the second slide, and then go straight to the second slide.  Like a fake transition.

Comment: @Paul That's more or less my fallback solution, except I copied the entire contents of the second slide over the first individually instead of as an image to preserve quality. The downside to this approach is that it makes working with individual elements on the transition slide with two sets of content very difficult.

Comment: I was in a similar situation earlier... and I found no "proper" solution after immense research.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Paul's answer above, I found a way to do something like this. Not sure it will help OP, but it might help people trying to do the same kind of thing in future. Happy to clarify if anything is unclear. (This works in PowerPoint 2013. Not tried in other versions.)

Step 1: Create your first slide

Step 2: Create your second slide (which I'll call the 'target' slide)

Step 2a: The transition between the two slides in question should be set to 'None' with no delay or anything--the slide should change immediately on whatever trigger you set. If you don't do this, the animation won't start until the transition 'animation' has completed. I.e., any animation you want to go 'over the transition' won't start until after the transition finishes.

Step 3: Set all the content you want to remain on the target slide after the 'transition' to 'Fade' in, 'With Previous' (so that the box that shows the order of the animation says 0), with a delay (so that the animation starts before the content on the target slide appears)

Step 4: Copy the content from the first slide you want to 'animate across the transition' onto the target slide and set up the animation you want, set it to start 'With Previous', without a delay

My use case was to have an image that took up a whole slide move over to simultaneously shrink and move to the right, while some text that related to the image appeared in a bulleted list, and the title faded in.

(Getting the image to be lined up right on the target slide took some trial and error, but I figured out one partial shortcut for that, too. Not really a shortcut, it's just the way, I just didn't know it: you can find out the size that the image is shrunk to, in my case 50%, then set the image on the target slide to be 50% the size  it is on the first slide. I'm not sure how to find out exactly where the end of a 'Move' animation ends up, but it's relatively simple to do this by trial and error, too. Just run the transition between the two slides and pay attention to where your animation ends up in relation to where you want the final image to be and either adjust the position of the final image, or the path of the animation.)